# Zend Framework - How can I subdivide an application in two?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, reusability, code-reuse, zend-framework3

I'm working in a project with many modules, these modules may refer to classes from another module.
Exemple:

```
ControllerModule1 { 
  $newClass = new ClassModule2();
}
```

My question is... Is there a way of creating another Zend Application (ZendApp2) for Module2, and still use its classes in the ZendApp1 without replicate the code?

Answer (score 0):

Modules are autoloaded from both `./module` and `./vendor`: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/application.config.php#L18-L21. So you can install a ZF module with Composer in the same way as you would any other PHP library.

In your example, you would break Module2 out into its own codebase, and then include it in both ZendApp1 and ZendApp2 via. Composer.